# Authorization Rules in Azure App Service is not working

Tags: json, azure, azure-web-app-service

I followed instructions on [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/11/17/url-authorization-rules/) trying to enable anonymous access for the home page and redirect to Google if accessing /Admin page using this authorization.json.

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "path_prefix": "/",
      "policies": { "unauthenticated_action": "AllowAnonymous" }
    },
    {
      "path_prefix": "/Admin",
      "policies": { "unauthenticated_action": "RedirectToLoginPage" }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I access the home page @ http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/ it always navigates me to login page. And after I login then post redirection I am getting following errors inside log streaming.

```
2016-12-02T04:30:44  PID[11016] Verbose     [Routes(Preview)] Attempting to load configuration from 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\authorization.json'.
2016-12-02T04:30:44  PID[11016] Critical    System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Routes.RoutesConfig. Encountered unexpected character 'ï'. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Encountered unexpected character 'ï'.
   at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlException exception)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonReader.ReadAttributes()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonReader.ReadNonExistentElementName(StringHandleConstStringType elementName)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement(XmlDictionaryString localName, XmlDictionaryString namespaceUri)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator.IsStartElement(XmlDictionaryString localname, XmlDictionaryString ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.IsRootElement(XmlReaderDelegator reader, DataContract contract, XmlDictionaryString name, XmlDictionaryString ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.InternalIsStartObject(XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication.ModuleUtils.DecodeJson[T](Stream jsonStream)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Routes.RoutesConfig.TryLoadFromFile(String configFilePath, Func`2 deserializer, RoutesConfig& config)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Routes.RoutesConfig.TryLoadFromJsonFile(String configFilePath, RoutesConfig& config)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Routes.RoutesModule.TryLoadRoutesConfig(HttpContextBase context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Routes.RoutesModule.<OnPostAuthenticateRequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication.HttpModuleDispatcher.<DispatchAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
2016-12-02T04:30:44  PID[11016] Information Sending response: 500.79 Internal Server Error
```

Additional details.
1. Re-started the site after publishing from visual studio as mentioned.
2. Those /Admin path I have inside AdminController. 
3. The authorization.json is at the root of the site. If I navigate to PS D:\home\site\wwwroot>  I am able to see the authorization.json file.

I don't know what I am getting wrong regarding the syntax of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your description, I followed [URL Authorization Rules](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/11/17/url-authorization-rules/) and created the authorization.json in my Visual Studio. I could make it work as expected on my Azure Web App.

https://bruce-chen-001.azurewebsites.net/

https://bruce-chen-001.azurewebsites.net/admin/admin.html

I assumed that there be something wrong with your authorization.json file. I found a similar issue about [Encountered unexpected character ‘ï’ error serializing JSON](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2014/03/19/encountered-unexpected-character-error-serializing-json/), you could refer to it.

**Updated**

Here is my authorization.json file:

[image]

Please make sure you have chosen **Allow Anonymous requests (no action)** under the “Action to take when request is not authenticated” in the Authentication/Authorization blade of your App Service on Azure Portal.

[image]

Comment: Can you update your answer to include authorization.json file you used for your website? I followed the msdn article to clear that characters and tried again and restarted the website but still on navigating to / it doesn't allow anonymous  login.

Comment: @Mitul I have updated my answer. Please see my updates.

Comment: I had on Action to take when request is not authenticated set to "Log in with Google". Changed it to Allow Anonymous requests (no action) and it works. Thanks.

Comment: I found weird issue where authorization.json file is expected to be have CRLF bytes. If this file has LF bytes then it was resulting into 503 http status code.